# Scraping Billboard Data with Python; code doesn't crawl to previous chart

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, web-scraping, while-loop

First of all, I'm a relative newbie to coding. My goal is to scrape at least the last decade of Billboard Hot 100 charts using the Python code below with billboard.py. My hiccup is I have tried a few variants of while loop statements and none have seemed to work to get me to the previous chart. I have an idea of how it should look from the billboard.py documentation but for whatever reason my code terminates prematurely or outputs an `AttributeError: 'ChartEntry' object has no attribute 'previousDate'`

Any advice on debugging this and/or corrective code is appreciated. Thank you.

```
import billboard
import csv

chart = billboard.ChartData('hot-100')
#chart = billboard.ChartData('hot-100', date=None, fetch=True, max_retries=5, timeout=25)

f = open('Hot100.csv', 'w')

headers = 'title, artist, peakPos, lastPos, weeks, rank, date\n'
f.write(headers)
while chart.previousDate:
    date = chart.date

    for chart in chart:
        title = chart.title
        artist = chart.artist
        peakPos = str(chart.peakPos)
        lastPos = str(chart.lastPos)
        weeks = str(chart.weeks)
        rank = str(chart.rank)

        f.write('\"' + title + '\",\"' + artist.replace('Featuring', 'Feat.') + '\",' + peakPos + ',' + lastPos + ',' + weeks + ',' + rank + ',' + date + '\n')
chart = billboard.ChartData('hot-100', chart.previousDate)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had to change how my script was comprehending the for loop.
My revised code below

```
import billboard
import csv

chart = billboard.ChartData('hot-100')
#chart = billboard.ChartData('hot-100', date=None, fetch=True, max_retries=5, timeout=25)

f = open('hot-100.csv', 'w')

headers = 'title, artist, peakPos, lastPos, weeks, rank, date\n'
f.write(headers)

date = chart.date

while chart.previousDate:
    date = chart.date
    for song in chart:
        title = song.title
        artist = song.artist
        peakPos = str(song.peakPos)
        lastPos = str(song.lastPos)
        weeks = str(song.weeks)
        rank = str(song.rank)

        f.write('\"' + title + '\",\"' + artist.replace('Featuring', 'Feat.') + '\",' + peakPos + ',' + lastPos + ',' + weeks + ',' + rank + ',' + date + '\n')
    chart = billboard.ChartData('hot-100', chart.previousDate)
    
f.close()
```